# Bad predictions but good model accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I was trying to build my first Keras deep neural network on Tensorflow and want to deployed it using Flask. I took a sample data airline data and wanted to predict if the flight gets delayed or not. To start with, I took only sample columns : `Year, Month, DayOfWeek, UniqueCarrier, FlightNum, Origin, Dest, Distance`. Converted `UniqueCarrier, Origin, Dest` into numeric values using label encoder. Then after running the below program found the accuracy to be 93%. But when I run a prediction manually by sending the parameters through rest api then I always get 1 as output. Not sure as what needs to be done.

Below is some of the code and Sample output:

```
  le = LabelEncoder()

  data["UniqueCarrier"] = le.fit_transform(data["UniqueCarrier"])
  UniqueCarrier = list(le.classes_)
  print(UniqueCarrier)
  data["Origin"] = le.fit_transform(data["Origin"])
  Carrier = list(le.classes_)
  print(Carrier)
  data["Dest"] = le.fit_transform(data["Dest"])
  TailNum = list(le.classes_)
  print(TailNum)
```

**Data set up as predictors and target:**

```
rfDataOriginal = pd.DataFrame(data)
Delay_YesNo = rfDataOriginal['IsDepDelayed']
rfDataOriginal.drop(['IsDepDelayed'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**Removing target variable:**

```
print('Dimension reduced to:')
print(len(rfDataOriginal.columns))
```

**Feature Scaling:**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

**Creating the model:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(15, input_dim=12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

**Compiling model:**

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Log for Tensorboard graph purpose:**

```
import keras
tbCallBack = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/keras_logs',  write_graph=True)
```

**Fitting the model:**

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=30,  verbose=1, callbacks=[tbCallBack])
```

**Creating the confusion matrix:**

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, Y_pred)
print("\nConfusion Matrix:")
print(cm)
acs = accuracy_score(y_test, Y_pred)
print("\nAccuracy Score: %.2f%%" % (acs * 100))

Confusion Matrix:
[[41614   322]
[ 5664 35894]]

 Accuracy Score: 92.83%
```

**Prediction Testing by passing parameters:**

```
inputFeature = [1989, 9, 14, 1719, 1720, 1845, 1859, 11, 927, 58, 68, 997]
inputFeature = np.asarray(inputFeature).reshape(1, 12)
model.predict(inputFeature)

Output: array([[ 1.]], dtype=float32)

inputFeature = [1989, 11, 24, 1144, 1144, 1633, 1635, 0, 816, 213, 59, 1205]
inputFeature = np.asarray(inputFeature).reshape(1, 12)
model.predict(inputFeature)

array([[ 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Do you get correct results if you perform prediction normally (i.e. without doing it using a rest api)?

Comment: Seems you have a class imbalance issue. How many samples per class you have? Is `1` the majority class?

Comment: This seems about right: all flights are delayed. That perfectly matches my experience.